# Contractivity of the Lindblad Generator Adjoint

Tags: quantum-mechanics, time-evolution, open-quantum-systems

In the context of the Lindblad equation in the Heisenberg picture, the adjoint of the Lindblad generator, denoted as $\mathcal{L}^\dagger$, is known to be non-contractive in different cases. I would like to gain a deeper understanding of the conditions under which we can assert that $\mathcal{L}^\dagger$ forms a contraction semigroup. Specifically, I would like to know the complete set of assumptions that guarantee the contraction property. Also I want to know the role of the detailed balance condition in this issue.

Additionally, I am curious about why $\mathcal{L}^\dagger$ does not preserve the property of contraction but preserve the Hermiticity, that is responsible for the time evolution of observables. This last statement may have some ambiguity. Let me know if this is the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property of contractivity depends on the norms that are used.
(Unfortunately, that seems to be often glossed over in textbooks.)
To answer your question, we have to quickly discuss the involved norms.
$\newcommand{\tr}{\operatorname{tr}}$

For an operator $X$, the Schatten-p-norms are defined as $ \lVert X \rVert_p = \bigl( \tr\bigl[ \lvert X \rvert^p \bigr] \bigr)^{1/p} $.
Note that $p=1$ is the trace norm, $p=\infty$ is the operator norm, and $p=2$ is the norm induced by the Hilbert-Schmidt product $\langle X, Y \rangle = \tr[ X^\dagger Y ]$.
For a superoperator $\mathcal L$, we consider the operator norms induced by the Schatten norms:
$$ \lVert \mathcal L \rVert_p = \sup_X\bigl( \lVert \mathcal L X \rVert_p : \lVert X \rVert_p = 1 \bigr) . $$
They satisfy the duality relation $\lVert \mathcal L \rVert_p = \lVert \mathcal L^\dagger \rVert_q$, where $\mathcal L^\dagger$ is the adjoint with respect to the Hilbert-Schmidt product and $1/p + 1/q = 1$.

Every positive trace-preserving superoperator is contractive with respect to the trace norm. Therefore, Lindbladians generate contractive semigroups, $\lVert e^{\mathcal L t} \rVert_1 \leq 1$. By the duality relation above, the adjoint $\mathcal L^\dagger$ therefore also generates a contractive semigroup, but with respect to a different norm:
$$ \lVert e^{\mathcal L^\dagger t} \rVert_\infty \leq 1 . $$
The question when $\mathcal L^\dagger$ is contractive in the trace norm is answered by a theorem in this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0601063.
The following statements are all equivalent:

- $\mathcal L$ is contractive for some $p > 1$ (and by duality, $\mathcal L^\dagger$ is contractive for some $p < \infty$)
- $\mathcal L$ is contractive for all $p$ (and by duality, $\mathcal L^\dagger$ is contractive for all $p$)
- $\mathcal L$ is unital ($\mathcal L(1) = 0$)

Regarding your second question, I am not sure if I understand your question. Both $\mathcal L$ and $\mathcal L^\dagger$ must preserve Hermiticity (and they do), because otherwise they could transform a state (observable) into something that is not a state (observable) which doesn't make any physical sense.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
- First of all usually people put $\| \|$ without any $p$ and I want to know what do they mean by that. According to your explanation operator norm is when $p=\infty$ but then you define contractivity of lindblad based on trace norm. For example in Neuman series says about operator norm. then it means that if I have $\mathcal{L}$ I should use trace norm that $p=1$ and if it is $\mathcal{L}^\dagger$ I should use $p=\infty$? 
 @Noiralef

Comment: - According to your answer it means that it is not possible to have both generator and its adjoint cntractive at the same time because their definition that we should use for norm is different. Am I right? @Noiralef

Comment: @Testina When people put $\lVert \cdots \rVert$ without a $p$, they should ideally explain what they mean by that. If they don't, we have to infer it from the context. When talking about quantum states, people often mean the trace norm. What I am saying is that $\mathcal L$ is always contractive for the trace norm and $\mathcal L^\dagger$ is always contractive for the operator norm. $\mathcal L^\dagger$ is also contractive for the trace norm if and only if both are contractive for all $p$-norms if and only if $\mathcal L$ is unital.

Comment: Do you know any sources that specifically talk about the generators and their adjoint in this sense. Because In most of cases in open quantum systems people wasn't that much precise and even they do not talk about the adjoint part.Because I need to show that norm of the adjoint of lindblad generator is less than one. @Noiralef

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know many sources either. The book "Open Quantum Systems. An Introduction" by Rivas and Huelga is a good start, and of course the article linked above. An honorable mention goes to chapter X.8 in vol 2 of the books by Reed and Simon, but they discuss contractive semigroups much more generally and don't mention Lindbladians or operator spaces. Two more papers mentioning such issues are https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.79.052326 and (self-advertisement) https://doi.org/10.1088/1751-8121/ab435a